# How to slide in text from off-screen left to be appended to existing centered sentence before centering both

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I am building a simple holding page for a friend's new construction company. When the page loads, the company name is centered horizontally on the page across two lines:

Blue Quarter

Construction

When the page loads, he wants the text "Website Under" to slide in from off-screen left in the same row as "Construction" before both words center relative to the window.

Blue Quarter

Website Under Construction

(sorry, wasn't sure how to center text within the question...)

I've so far placed both parts of the text which require animation in a div set to display inline. I have found some code which uses CSS keyframes but this animates both bits the same and also doesn't work taking the "Website Under" text off the left-hand side of the display.

```
<div class="headline">    
<h1 class="under-anim" >WEBSITE UNDER </h1>
<h1 class="construction">CONSTRUCTION</h1>
</div>
```

```
@keyframes slide-right {
  from {
    margin-left: -100%;
    width: 0%; 
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.headline {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}


.headline h1 {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 57pt;
}

h1.construction {
    color: #BCBDC0; 
}

h1.under-anim {
    color: #DCDDDF;
    animation: 5s slide-right;
}
```

I think I require some help with coding multiple keyframes. First bringing the text "Website Under" in from the left, and once it is in position next to "Construction" sliding both so that they are fully centered. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not really sure what are you trying to achieve. I tried the code and it goes from off-screen left. What it should do?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. When the site loads, he wants the word "construction" to be centred on the page. Next, the words "website under" should slide in from off off-left to join "construction" to make the whole phrase "website under construction". Then the whole phrase should slide to be fully centred on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var $div = $("<div/>",{"class":"under-anim","text":"WEBSITE UNDER "});
  $('.slides').prepend($div);
 
  $div.css({left:-1000,opacity : 0 });
  $div.animate({
    'left':0,
    'opacity' : 1
  },2000);
});
```

```css
.slides {
  width: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.slides div {
  position:relative;
  display:inline;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
.construction {
  color: #BCBDC0; 
}
.under-anim {
  color: #DCDDDF;
}
```

```html
<div class="slides">
  <div class="construction">CONSTRUCTION</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Can you use jQuery? I make an example for you using jQuery and `animate`. I made the `font-size` smaller, to see how it works in the snippet. Could this help you?

Comment: Hi Valentin. jQuery is fine for this project and thank you so much for taking the time to post your code. It's very close to what I'm trying to achieve. The only difference is that I need "construction" to begin centred. Once "website under" slides in, the whole sentence needs to centre, as it does with the ending position in your code.

Comment: This has set me on the path to the solution. I will finish the code and post it shortly. Thanks again Valentin!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
var $div = $("<div/>",{"class":"under-anim","text":"WEBSITE UNDER "});
$('.slides').prepend($div);
$('.slides').css('margin-left', -$('.under-anim').width()/2);
$div.css({left:-1000,opacity : 0 });
$div.animate({'left':0,'opacity' : 1},2000, function (){
$('.slides').animate({ 'margin-left': '0px', opacity: 0.5 }, 1000);
});
});
```

```css
.slides {
  width: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
.slides div {
  position:relative;
  display:inline;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20pt;
}
.construction {
  color: #BCBDC0; 
}
.under-anim {
  color: #DCDDDF;
}
```

```html
<div class="slides">
  <div class="construction">CONSTRUCTION</div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wondered if it could be done by css alone.

```css
.outer {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;

    overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
    /* shrink-to-fit width */
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    /* shift left edge of text to center */
    left: 50%;
}
.text {
    /* shift left edge of text half distance to left */
    margin-left: -50%;
    /* text should all be on one line */
    white-space: nowrap;

}


.myspace {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  animation: shrinkspace 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  
  
  
  }

.mycopy {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: transparent;
  
  animation: shrinkcopy 3s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  
}

@keyframes shrinkcopy{
0% {
               max-width: 16em;
            }       
     
            100% {
               max-width: 0em;
            }
         }



@keyframes shrinkspace {
0% {
               width: 500px;
            }       
     
            100% {
               width: 0px;
            }
         }
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"><div class="text">


Blue Quarter

</div></div></div>
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"><div class="text">

Website under 
<span class='myspace'></span>

Construction

<span class='myspace'></span>
<span class='mycopy'>
Website under
</span>


</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Hi Hans. That's where I was heading originally so thank you for providing an alternative to jQuery. Brilliant!